# Templated static member function pointer initialization

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

```
template<class K> 
class Cltest
{
public:
    static double (K::*fn)(double);
};

template<class K> 
double K::*Cltest<K>::fn(double) = NULL;
```

How can I initialize the static member function pointer?

Comment: I am not sure, but can't you do it just like you initialized it to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose `*fn` in braces.
Corrected syntax:

```
template<class K> 
double (K::*Cltest<K>::fn)(double) = 0;
```

Comment: As always, I am 5 seconds late ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you simplify the syntax using appropriate typedef, then it is much easier to do that:

```
template<class K> 
class Cltest
{
public:
    typedef double (K::*Fn)(double); //use typedef
    static Fn fn;
};

template<class K> 
typename Cltest<K>::Fn Cltest<K>::fn = 0;

//Or you can initialize like this:
template<class K> 
typename Cltest<K>::Fn Cltest<K>::fn = &K::SomeFun;
```

Using `typedef`, you actually separate the *type* of the function from the *variable* name. Now you can see at them separately which makes it easier to understand the code. For example, above `Cltest<K>::Fn` is the *type* and `Cltest<K>::fn` is the *variable* of that type.